Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'
class SimpleKeyboardInputMask {
  init = keyboard => {
...
}

export default SimpleKeyboardInputMask;

Этот модуль я я взял из библиотеки. Смотрел чужие топики по проблеме, но ни один вариант экспорта (ни через модули, ни через default) не подошёл. Reference error или Uncaught SyntaxError и всё тут. Нашёл относительно других импортов в разметке следующий скрипт:
  <script type="importmap">
    {
      "imports": {
        "three": "/lib/three/three.module.min.js",
        "three/": "/lib/three/",
        "js/": "/js/",
        "lib/": "/lib/"
      }
    }
  </script>  

И вот это:
<script type="module">
  import * as THREE from "three"
  window.THREE = THREE;
  // for bindings
</script>

Можете объяснить что происходит во втором куске кода? Если я не прав тыкните носом в тему о чём почитать. Если что, статью на MDN об export глянул, вроде не то.

ошибка в браузере возникает или в node? файл с кодом экспорта подключен как(если браузер, должен быть type=module)

Да ошибка в браузере уже, ниже для этого  JSON есть

Это ключик к разгадке? Блин, щас в вопрос вставлю @SwaD

Файл подключен как обычный script

А ругается то у вас на экспорт.

О модулях отдельная статья MDN есть: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules (обращаю внимание на разделы "добавление на страницу" и "отличия от обычных скриптов") Обратите внимание на особенности, что import/export работают только в модулях, что тестирование должно идти через сервер, для чего нужен importmap и как он задает пути.

ахахахаха это мой вопрос думаю че все знакомое такое
